# Iterating through a list of floats to compare to another list of float

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'd like to compare (greater than or equal to) a list of floats to another lists of float by iteraing through the first list.  This is for predicting probabilities based on thresholds.

```py
probs = [0.886,0.375,0.174,0.817,0.574,0.319,0.812,0.314,0.098,0.741,
         0.847,0.202,0.31,0.073,0.179,0.917,0.64,0.388,0.116,0.72]
thresholds = [0.00, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]
    
x={}
for i in thresholds:
    if i <= probs #comparing one value of thresholds to all values of probs
        x.append(0)
    else:
        x.append(1)
```

I'd like to get 5 separate lists of predictions based on the probabilities for each value of the thresholds.  Common errors are:  'float is not iterable' or 'cannot compare between int and float type' or 'truth is ambiguous'.  I have attempted to use the range(len(x)), float(x) for x in probs, list(map(lambda x:x[i] for i in thresholds], probs)).  I seem to be unable to address the foundational issues of 'floats are not iterable' and comparing floats to ints.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Those errors that you get are not errors that you would get from working with 2 python lists of floats. Instead they seem to be `numpy` or `pandas` related. What exactly are the data structures that you are working with?

Comment: More importantly, some list of errors is useless, what is the error that the code in the question produces? It can only be one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Create a histogram of your `probs` and use `thresholds` as bins/bin edges.